# Ordinal encoding in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

Is there a way to have `pandas.get_dummies` output the numerical representation in **one** column rather than a separate column for each option?

Concretely, currently when using `pandas.get_dummies` it gives me a column for every option:

| Size | Size_Big | Size_Medium | Size_Small |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Big | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Medium | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Small | 0 | 0 | 1 |

But I'm looking for more of the following output:

| Size | Size_Numerical |
| --- | --- |
| Big | 1 |
| Medium | 2 |
| Small | 3 |

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want dummies, you want factors/categories.

Use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
df['Size_Numerical'] = pd.factorize(df['Size'])[0] + 1
```

output:

```
     Size  Size_Numerical
0     Big               1
1  Medium               2
2   Small               3
```

Answer (score 2):

I think OneHotEncoding has a similar issue that it expands and creates n-dimensions as labels. You need to use [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) so that:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['Sizes'])
df['Category'] = le.transform(df['Sizes']) + 1
```

Outputs:

```
    Sizes  Category
0   Small         3
1  Medium         2
2   Large         1
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Pandas isn't an absolute requirement, sklearn has an OrdinalEncoder that does exactly that ([source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html))

Comment: This causes the issue OP wishes to avoid.

Comment: My mistake, I meant to discuss the OrdinalEncoder - will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

With [`category`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), you could do

```py
(
    dataf
    .astype({"Size":"category"})
    .assign(Size_Numerical = lambda d : d["Size"].cat.rename_categories({"Big": 1, "Medium": 2, "Small": 3})
    )

)
```

Tested with data

```py
import pandas as pd


dataf = pd.DataFrame({'Size':["Big", "Medium", "Small","Medium"]})
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to the `Categorical` type and get `codes`:

```
pd.Categorical(['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C']).codes
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int8)
```